Optimizing Record Parsing from DynamoDB PartiQL Query Execution via Python
I am running PartiQL queries against my DynamoDB tables using boto3 and I want to be able to parse these records into a tabular format (pandas DataFrame).
This is what my code looks like:
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer
import panads as pd


connection = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    **config # This contains my credentials
)

result = connection.execute_statement(Statement=query)

records = []
if result['Items']:
    # TODO: Can parsing be optimized?
    records.extend(parse_records(result['Items']))

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in result:
        result = connection.execute_statement(
            Statement=query,
            NextToken=result['NextToken']
        )
        records.extend(parse_records(result['Items']))

df = pd.json_normalize(records)


def parse_records(records: List[Dict]) -> Dict:
    """
    Parses the records returned by the PartiQL query execution.

    Args:
        records (List[Dict]): A list of records returned by the PartiQL query execution.

    Returns:
        Dict: A dictionary containing the parsed record.
    """
    deserializer = TypeDeserializer()
    
    parsed_records = []
    for record in records:
        parsed_records.append({k: deserializer.deserialize(v) for k,v in record.items()})

    return parsed_records

Is it possible for me to avoid looping through all of the records in order to parse them? I am looking to optimize this part of the program. I am open to other approaches as well as long as I am able to execute PartQL queries.

You could save already deserialised records in S3 like csv of JSON file, and then use DynamoDB Streams to track any changes.
You could subscribe for these changes by AWS Lambda and update your existing S3 file by new records.
This approach going to work well for huge DynamoDB Tables, that update frequently.
There is no way to deserialise all records, without iterating through all of them, but you could increase speed of your program by parallelism, for example you could make queries in different threads.
